# BufferedInputStream and Blocking

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedinputstream

I am using a `BufferedInputStream` to read from a socket. The `BufferedInputStream` reads as follows:

```
socketInput.read(replyBuffer, 0, 7);
```

It is instantiated by

```
socketInput = new BufferedInputStream(mySocket.getInputStream());
```

`mySocket` is defined as `private Socket mySocket;`

`mySocket` is instantiated by `mySocket = new Socket(ipAddress, port);`

I have verified that `mySocket` is connected to my device. I can send data to my device; however, I am not receiving from my device for unknown reasons but that is not the problem.

I want my `BufferedInputStream` to return after say 100ms if it does not read any data. Can the `BufferedInputStream` be setup to do this? Right now, it blocks indefinitely.

Comment: If you want any kind of non-blocking or timeout I/O, you should use the NIO (`java.nio`) classes, not stuff in `java.io`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's generally a bad idea to use a buffered stream for reading from a socket, for exactly this reason: it will wait forever if it doesn't see enough data to fill its internal buffer (which is going to be larger than 7 characters!) There's no way to make it time out. Just use the `SocketInputStream` directly, and the problem goes away.

Comment: so you are recommending instead socket.getInputStream.read(..)?

Comment: Yes, that's it. Then you can use `setSoTimeout()`, as another poster suggested, and you'll get the behavior you want.

Answer (score 5):

Specify 100ms timeout for your socket. [setSoTimeout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout(int))

Comment: is this still valid if I am using a BufferedInputStream?

Comment: What will happen is you'll get a `SocketTimeoutException` from your `read()` call, even though there were actually enough bytes to satisfy your request. That's not good.

Comment: @Code Monkey it's still valid for any wrapping InputStream.

Comment: @Ernest Friedman-Hill SocketTimeoutException throws if no data available.